# Launching shell command in Eshell without prompt interfence

Tags: emacs, elisp, eshell

I'm trying to customize my eshell to intercept `python` to do two things:

1. Open a new window and run python if no arguments are given (e.g., `$ python`)
2. Run the command "per usual" if arguments are given (e.g., `$ python foobar.py`)

So far I have something like this

```
(defun eshell/python (&rest cmd-args)
  (if (not cmd-args)
       (progn (run-python "python")
              (select-window (split-window-below))
              (switch-to-buffer "*Python*")
              (balance-windows)
        nil)
  (message "Use '*python' to call python directly")))
```

I've tried replacing `(message ...)` with a few different things:

Based on the ouput of `eshell-parse-command "python test.py"` I tried

```
(progn (eshell-trap-errors
         (eshell-named-command "python" cmd-args)))
```

but it hits a recursion limit.

Since `*python test.py` does what I want, I then tried

```
(progn (eshell-trap-errors
         (eshell-named-command (concat "*" "python") cmd-args)))
```

but that puts the python process in the background and interrupts stdout with the output of my `eshell-prompt-function.`

Finally, I've fiddled with `shell-command` but I can't get it to write to the eshell buffer. In particular,

```
(progn (eshell-trap-errors
        (shell-command (mapconcat (lambda(x) x) cmd-args " ")
                       (get-buffer "*eshell*") (get-buffer "*eshell*"))))
```

gives me a `Text is read only` message and moves point to start of the eshell buffer.

Is what I'm looking for possible?

**Edit 1** 
Running without `eshell/python` defined, I've instead tried to avoid alias problems:

```
(defun eshell/gvr (&rest cmd-args)
  (if (not cmd-args)
      (progn (run-python "python")
             (select-window (split-window-below))
             (switch-to-buffer "*Python*")
             (balance-windows)
             nil)
    (progn (eshell-trap-errors
            (eshell-named-command "python" cmd-args)))))
```

If `test.py` is

```
print "Hello World"
x = raw_input("What should I repeat? ")
print x
```

running `gvr test.py` in eshell fails when I reply to the prompt because eshell tries to execute the input instead of handing it to python, but running `python test.py` goes off without a hitch.

How can I get run my own subprocesses in eshell the same way that they happen by default?